# FileReader does not render the image from multiple files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this multiple type file input and then when onChange event is triggered unto the input file then it will loop through each file and then create a FileReader() and then render each file to an image but seems it only render the first one and not each file, any ideas, help please?

```js
document.querySelector("input")
    .onchange = function(e) {
      for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            img.src = e.target.result;
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[i]);
      }
    }
```

```css
img{
width:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" multiple><br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileReader` returns results asynchronously. You can create a closure to use within `for` loop to process each file.

```js
document.querySelector("input")
  .onchange = function(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
      // use IIFE as a closure
      (function(file) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          img.src = e.target.result;
          document.body.appendChild(img);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      })(e.target.files[i]); // pass current File to closure 
    }
  }
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" multiple><br><br><br>
```